# How to split several IP addresses and then ping each of them?

Tags: linux, shell, sh

In a file named `input.txt`, I have a string formatted like this:

```
10.0.0.1:130.0.0.2:192.168.1.1:...
```

I want to split these IP addresses and ping each of them and save ping results in `output.txt`. I should do this with a Linux sh script. I used this code:

```
 for line in $(cat /input.txt | sed s/:/\\n/g)
 do  
 ping -c 3 $line > /output.txt
 done
```

But only the ping of the first IP address is saved in the output file.

I don't know how to do it correctly.

Thanks all.

Comment: Are you sure it is the *first* IP that is saved to `output.txt`? With this script I get only the *last* one, because every time the `ping` line is executed, `>` erases the entire file before writing to `output.txt`, try with `>>` instead (which appends to the file rather that overwriting it).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I checked it again and replace `>>` with `>`, but it saves _first_  ip!

Comment: I tested this code with `>>`, and it works, can you give an example of input and output you get?

Comment: @F.M: One note about the code you posted: saving files in the root directory `/` is considered "a bad thing to do" (see http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_2.3/fhs-2.3.html#THEROOTFILESYSTEM) . It's better to save files in your home directory (or `/tmp`).

Comment: I restart my system and then test the code. It works if ping of all ip addresses success. When a network is unreachable, it ends the loop and cannot continue!!! I don't know what is the correct code?